# How much of First Order—ships and troops—are still around after the events of the “The Last Jedi.”

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

While *The Last Jedi* makes it clear that…

> …the whole Resistance fleet–and much of the Resistance—was destroyed…

…what about the First Order’s fleet? It’s odd to me that so much of the film’s span consisted of…

> …the First Order’s ships chasing the Resistance ships. If the First Order still had a large and functional fleet, could they have not called on backup to just swoop in an cut off the Resistance ships.

***Please provide references and details.***

Answer (score 8):

### Looks like First Order fleet was hit badly.

There is no definite proof, but the one and only [mega-class Star Dreadnought](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Mega-class_Star_Dreadnought) was destroyed :) [*Supremacy*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Supremacy) served as a flagship and some sort of capitol for First Order, which by itself is nomadic. Wookieepedia cites various sources and claims that First Order officers practically lived on their ships and considered them home.

Wookieepedia also claims that [The Resistance during that time suspected that at least 30 Resurgent-class Star Destroyers were present among the First Order forces](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Resurgent-class_Star_Destroyer).

There is another line: [Taking inspiration from the Imperial-class Star Destroyers of the Old Empire, but lacking the resources to construct huge numbers of these capital ships, First Order designs would consciously emulate the psychological factor of the previous Imperial Era ships](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Resurgent-class_Star_Destroyer).

For all of this we could conclude that First Order never had numerical strength of Empire, and therefore sustained significant casualties after the events in the latest movie.

Comment: Also, the ships that were pursuing the resistance didn't seem to have any reason to expect the resistance could possibly get away. I assumed that there was plenty of ships off in other areas of the galaxy, and simply there was no reason to bring them in. The First Order was mostly correct in that it was just a matter of time before the resistance ran out of fuel and got destroyed. Certainly they were winning and massively outgunned the resistance at the start. The tide only turned after the hyperspace trick, at which point the resistance didn't really have a fleet anymore.

Comment: The above is mostly to address OP's question of why the First Order didn't just have some other ships come in from the opposite direction to surround the resistance. Plus, moving in extra ships would distract a considerable chunk of the First Order from their other duties (they surely have a lot going on besides dealing with the resistance). There just wasn't a need to bring in any more ships.

Answer (score -3):

I'm not sure, but I think their fleet is not necessarily in a good way at this point. Holdo's sacrifice destroyed the *Supremacy*, which was actually the roving capital of the First Order, as well as several star destroyers with ricochets. And one of their Mandator IVs bought it over D'Qar, so I think they've taken some serious losses.

Comment: There is currently no information on the size of the First Order's fleet or forces. Their fleet is likely just fine, just like the Empire's former fleet when chasing the Rebellion, scattered across the galaxy previously engaged...